# On some type of conjugate of elements of SL(n,Z)

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A\in SL(n,\mathbb{Z})$ and $B\in\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{Z})$ s.t. $\det(B)\ne 0$. Is it possible to find a power of $B^{-1}AB$ in $SL(n,\mathbb{Z})$?

Comment: I'm sure you mean a **positive** power. 

Comment: Yep! that's what I meant. 

Comment: Also: http://www.mathematik.uni-muenchen.de/~yarotsky/jarnik/selection_problems.pdf (problem 3) and http://www.mathematik.uni-muenchen.de/~yarotsky/jarnik/Jarnik_daniel_harrer.pdf .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Write $N = det(B)$. Then, the group $SL(n, \mathbb{Z} / N\mathbb{Z})$ is finite-order, say of order $k$. If we raise $B^{-1} A B$ to the power of $k$, then it should lie in $SL(n, \mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: I think you can safely erase the 'should'.